# How to fetch address bar url in jsp?

Tags: jsp

I am trying to fetch address bar URL in jsp. I have jsp running in Oracle EBS R12 version application server.

We have two URLs and both point to same server but based on URL the user is on, we need to display different message.

Two URLs:

```
catalog.store.com

catalog.mystore.com
```

both of above URL points to a server URL:

```
myserver.abc.com:5400/OA_HTML/myjspfilename.jsp
```

When my address bar points to `catalog.mystore.com`,
I did search on stackoverlflow with "how to fetch address bar URL in jsp" and looked all results. None of them is working for me.

3) All of these code:

`request.getRequestURL().toString()`  - this gives me: 
http://myserver.abc.com:5400/OA_HTML/myjspfilename.jsp

`request.getRequestURI()`  - this gives me: OA_HTML/myjspfilename.jsp

response.getHeader("referrer")  - this give me null.

`request.getServername()`  - this gives me: http://myserver.abc.com:5400

`request.getAttribute("javax.servlet.forward.request_uri")` - this gives me null.

Comment: `request.getRequestURL().toString()` ... if that doesn't work for you, nothing will.  What is the issue?

Comment: issue is : request.getRequestURL() is giving me server url , not the one I have in address bar. address bar shows    catalog.mystore.com/oa_html_myjspfile.jsp and getrequestURL shows me http://myserver.abc.com:5400/oa_html/myjspfilename.jsp

Comment: So is it a problem caused by some reverse proxy then?

Comment: not sure if DBA has set reverse proxy for the url. Lets say if they have, then how can I get address bar url ? Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: I think with a reverse proxy you'd look at the header X-Original-URL

Comment: can you please provide me the syntax if you have to fetch header X-Original-URL? Thank you.

Comment: DBA confirmed that they are using reverse proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances, `request.getRequestURL().toString()`.  With a reverse proxy you'd look at the header X-Original-URL.

```
String originalUrl = request.getHeader("X-Original-URL");
```

Comment: This x-original-url also comes up as null string. Any other option?

Comment: even X-Original-URL value is coming as null. We are using reverse proxy.

Comment: @techiens There might possibly be some settings in the reverse proxy to retain the address.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help. I am going to check with network team on that.